# Lost "start a bounty" button

Tags: support, bounty

I wanted to place a bounty on [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35389/there-is-are-more-than-one-whats-the-difference) Question, but I can't find a **start a bounty** button. I'm guessing this is a regressive bug. Or maybe I'm just going about it the wrong way.

Answer (score 2):

As per [the FAQ item](https://english.stackexchange.com/faq#bounty),

> Questions must be at least 2 days old to be eligible for a bounty.

Comment: That possibility did occur to me, though to be honest I didn't notice it in the FAQ. So I checked [this other question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/34902/youre-not-the-boss-of-me-vs-youre-not-my-boss) I asked a few days ago, where I haven't accepted any Answer yet. I can't see a **start a bounty** button there either.

Comment: "There can only be 1 active bounty per question and per user at any given time." You already have an active bounty on another question. @Fum

Comment: oic. Thanks for that. It had the intended effect, then! I figured it might be considered "in poor taste" to start a bounty without giving the Q a chance to get somewhere unaided. I kinda forgot I still had another one outstanding. Except to remember that I'd have to offer more than 50 for the new one because that wasn't enough to attract a better Answer on the current one.